# How did Anakin Skywalker learn Force Choke?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

Anakin Skywalker used Force Choke long before he become Sith. For example, he choked Poggle the Lesser during Clone Wars ([details here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_choke)).

Where and from whom would he learn this ability? Force Choke is clearly Dark Side power, I doubt it was taught by Jedi. **Was it something that anyone with Dark Side aptitude could use without much training?**

Comment: I mean, I don’t see why he couldn’t have figured it out by himself. It’s not as if Force choking is the only way to kill someone with Force telekinesis (as mentioned elsewhere on this site). It just has a nice combination of not requiring much precision and making the victim suffer.

Comment: I agree with Adamant.  We see that he has fine control over telekinesis in the films (e.g.: when he flies the apple over to Padme).  I don't think it takes any special training to choke someone; all you have to do is concentrate on the throat and squeeze.

Comment: I also suspect it's somewhat instinctive. Seems like a logical way of 'lashing out' with your Force powers, not like something that needs to be taught and practiced.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Force choke is merely an application of telekinesis any force user who has telekinetic ability could use force choke if they so desired.

Comment: Force Choke could also used at distance, sometimes even when target is light years away. Are you certain it is merely extension of telekinetic abilities ?

Comment: Luke force choked one of the Gamorrean guards in Jabba's palace at the beginning of ROTJ.

Comment: @rs.29: That's the "tele" part of "telekinesis".